# QuickTime Player crashes on startup

Tags: applications, crash, quicktime, mediaplayer

Suddenly I can't get QuickTime Player to work anymore because it crashes right after opening it. I do not know if this is the right error message from the log:

```
Application Specific Information:
Sandbox creation failed: Container object initialization failed.
NSCocoaErrorDomain:512
```

Does anyone know how to fix the problem or how to reinstall the application even if it's a system app?

Comment: What version of Quicktime Player?

Comment: Assuming your home directory is in its default installation place (i.e. you haven't moved it, or net boot) and, judging by the word "Suddenly", this is not the first time you attempt to launch QuickTime Player X, have you tried removing the container? `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX`

Comment: OK, removed it and the player works again. Thanks! :)

Comment: Btw, should I delete my question now or what?

Answer (score 9):

As [@Redarm](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/49869/redarm) suggested, you should remove the folder found at

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX
```

After that, quit and reopen QuickTime.

Comment: In case it helps, I got this error after installing Soundflower - some drivers to be able to record the output from the Mac - my Mac is the base model 16" 2019 model

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly similar fix on Mac Catalina. I searched for "com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX" in Finder, right clicked it, clicked "Show in Enclosing Folder" and then saw it was in a folder called "Autosaved Information".

It looks like it was holding on to some sort of corrupted video file that crashed QT, so every time I would open QT it would try to open the video, causing it to crash, and on and on.

Once I deleted everything in the Autosaved Information folder it worked again.